# How to modify DevOps story view

Tags: azure-devops

I need to track some additional data on user stories.
I am thinking to add a custom field to Taskboard/story view. Is it even possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is the documentation for your topic:

1. [Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops)
2. [Customize cards on a sprint taskboard in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/customize-taskboard?view=azure-devops)